# capture the second field and the last field from string

Tags: linux, awk, sed, perl

we have files with the follwing file name format

VER_{FILE NAME}_{VERSION}

example

```
  VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.2
```

we want to capture only the "FILE NAME" and "VERSION" number

so how to remove the first _ , and the last _  in the file name
so we can capture the "FILE NAME" and "VERSION" , ( with sed/awk or perl  one-liner )

example

```
 echo VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.2 | <some syntax>

 collect_important_info.pl  1.0.2
```

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl comes much more naturally to me than the lighter-weight alternatives:

```
echo VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.2 | perl -pe 's/^[^_]*_(.*)_(.*)$/$1 $2/'
```

If it doesn't matter that this uses a heavier weight process than necessary, I'd stop there.

sed can do it however, it just feels kludgey to have to have to escape basic elements like brackets:

```
echo VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.2 | sed 's/VER_\(.*\)_\(.*\)/\1 \2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$ echo VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.2 | sed 's/_/ /' | sed -r 's/(.*)_/\1 /' | awk -F" " '{print $2"\t"$3}'
```

The first sed is replacing the first occurrence of `_` and second sed does that with the last occurrence of `_` and finally awk to print

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.2' | 
    perl -F_ -lane 'print join("_", @F[1..@F-2]), " ", @F[@F-1]'
collect_important_info.pl 1.0.2
```

Note: `perl` arrays start from 0, not 1 so the array index for the second field is `[1]`, not `[2]`.

This splits the input into an array (`@F`), separated by `_` underscore characters.  Then it prints the 2nd through to the 2nd-last field (`@F[1..@F-2]`) joined by underscores, followed by a space, and then the last field (`@F[@F-1]`).

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

Sample files:

```
$ ls -1 VER_*_[0-9]*[0-9]
VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.2
VER_collect_some_info.pl_3.4.2
```

---

```
find . -type f -name "VER_*_[0-9]*[0-9]" -exec \
        bash -c 'v=${1##*_}; f=${1#*_}; f=${f%_*}; echo $f $v' _ {} \;
```

The output:

```
collect_some_info.pl 3.4.2
collect_important_info.pl 1.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk you can use:

```
echo VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.2 | awk -F '_' '{for (i=2; i<NF; i++) {{printf $i} if (i!=NF-1) printf "_"} printf " " $NF "\n"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got mentioned result by using combination of `sed` and `awk`

```
echo VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.2 |sed -r "s/_/ /1"| sed "s/_/ /3"| awk '{print $2,$NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run this perl script and pass the directory to look into as it's argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = $ARGV[0];
my @files = `find $dir -type f -name "VER_*_[0-9]*[0-9]"`;

my $all_files;
foreach my $file (@files) {
    $file =~ /VER_(.*)_(.*)/;
    $all_files .= $1."  ".$2."\n";
}

print $all_files if ($all_files);
```

Example:
I ran this script by passing current directory (.) as argument to it (which contains `VER_collect_important_info.pl_1.0.3`).

```
[mask@cent ~]$ perl separate_file_version.pl .  
collect_important_info.pl  1.0.3
```